# SQL(Need to print all the duplicate value IDs)

Tags: sql

```
Empid----Name
  1        aa
  2        bb
  3        cc
  4        aa
  5        bb
```

I need to get output  to print EmpId number for which names are repeated

```
output Required:
 1,2,4,5.
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: tell what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql server,use the below script.

```
;WITH CTE_1 AS
(
SELECT *,COUNT(1)OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) CNT
FROM [YourTable]
)
SELECT ID
FROM   [CTE_1] 
WHERE  CNT > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select empid from table
where name in (select name from table group by name having count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
         select distinct  t.Empid from
         #Your_Table t inner join 
         (
          select  Name, COUNT (Name) as count
          from #Your_Table
          group by Name
          having COUNT (Name) > 1
         )a  on a.Name=t.Name

         order by t.Empid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table AS parent 
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT * 
FROM table AS sub 
WHERE sub.Name == parent.Name && parent.Empid <> sub.Empid
)
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for? (Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.)

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) RowNo,*
      From Your_Table
   ) a
   WHERE RowNo > 1
```